# GRUB menu doesn't render properly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I just dual-booted my windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 12.04.03 on UEFI. No problems. The only thing is that the GRUB menu doesn't render properly. The text is all jagged up. Here's what I see:

[image]

What do I do??

Comment: It looks more like a problem with your hardware, not a problem with Ubuntu or grub.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like this before.

Comment: How old is your system?

Comment: A year or so, I guess

Comment: @comrademike I solved the issue, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but the following solved the problem:

My default bootloader was windows and it used to give some sort of an error (bootmanager.efi not found) and then I used to do a <kbd>F12</kbd> on the start screen to go to the Ubuntu GRUB menu where I used to get the jagged screen.

So what I did was, I went to the BIOS menu and made the GRUB the default bootloader and the next time I started up my machine, I got the normal purple GRUB menu without any problem.

Still no clue why this happened, but it seemed to work for me.

Comment: That seems like you have Windows in UEFI mode and Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. The only way you then can dual boot si from UEFI or one time boot key. UEFI & BIOS are not really compatible, so you cannot boot from grub menu as once you have started booting in one mode you cannot change.

Comment: It's working. I can dual boot smoothly from GRUB menu now

Comment: My suspicion is that the Windows boot loader was adjusting the screen resolution and GRUB was making invalid assumptions about the starting screen resolution, and so failed when launched after the Windows boot loader. When launched before the Windows boot loader did anything, though, GRUB would be fine.

Comment: I guess that was it. Btw @RodSmith can you direct me to a resource wherein I can learn more about GRUB. There seems to have been a lot of problems with mine lately.